# How to convert string to PDF Document byte array without creating pdf file into disk in Java

Tags: java, arrays, pdf, itext, document

I want to convert plain string to pdf document byte array in memory.

I have created a file in disc and reading back from memory. How can we do it without creating a file.

Below is the code:

```
    //Create Document instance.
    Document document = new Document();
    //Create pdf file
    File file = getFileFromResource(fileName);
    //Create OutputStream instance.
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    //Create PDFWriter instance.
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    //Open the document.
    document.open();
    //Add content to the document.
    document.add(new Paragraph(message));
    //Close document and outputStream.
    document.close();
    outputStream.close();

    //Read pdf file and convert to byte array
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper2 = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    stamper2.close();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    reader.close();
    return bytes;
```

Comment: Why don't you make the first 'outputStream' a ```ByteArrayOutputStream``` ?

Comment: Oh yes, that should work. Thanks